# How to Insert row into database for each row of a select in SQL?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I am trying to add a row to an Access database by running a query that will take the results of a SELECT Query and then grab that information to do a for loop, If I was using PHP or python I would know how to do this but I only can use microsoft access.

For example if I had a list customers and wanted to add customers whose subscriptions have ended the process would be like this.

1. Select Subscribers whose subscription end date is after NOW()
2. Take the name and number of each subscriber and add as a new row into the "Lost Customers" database
3. The "Lost Customers" database also has a "Subscription Status" column so I'd also like for every inserted row to have the value "Cancelled".

This is just an **example** to help explain what I need the query to do, this isn't what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question does not contain any database table descriptions so I can't show a real SQL solution, but a direction to look at is the fact that it is possible to create an INSERT statement using a SELECT statement:

```
INSERT INTO LOST_CUSTOMERS (CUST_NUM, CUST_NAME, STATUS)
 SELECT CUST_NUM, CUST_NAME, 'Cancelled'
   FROM CUSTOMERS
 WHERE END_DATE < now()
```

Remark: I assume you want the customer with an end date BEFORE now. All your currently active customers have an end date after now()

Comment: If I am Selecting from a different database to get this information lets call it CUST_INFO would it be different ?

Comment: Normally it is not possible to execute a single SQL statement over multiple databases. In Access you can create a linked table in your current database, pointing to a table in another database. If this is possible in your case, both tables are accessible with a single SQL statement. If linking is not possible I'm afraid you will have to build a RecordSet to fetch the records from the first database table and inserting the records within a loop over de result set.

Comment: Ok I think I can link the tables also WHERE clauses work fine with this correct?

Comment: with a linked table it behaves like an internal table so yes also where clauses and joins between tables work fine.

Answer (score 2):

You do this using `insert . . . select`.  The code looks something like:

```
insert into LoastCustomers(name, subscdribernuber, status)
    select name, subscribernum, 'Cancelled'
    from subscribers
    where subscriptionenddate >= now();
```